# How can i get the final salary?

Tags: python

I have an exercise where they give us 2 categories (A,B), each category has an increase in salary. Category A increases 1%, Category B increases 1.5%. I was thinking in this:

```
salary = float(input("whats your salary? "))
Category = input("whats your category(A,B)? ")
final_salary = salary + (salary* #the category chosen)
```

How can i redirect the category chosen so it can multiply for the salary??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to emulate a switch-case in python using dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190949/how-to-emulate-a-switch-case-in-python-using-dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dictionary. using `lower` you can avoid errors due to mismatches between the input and the dictionary keys

```
increase = {'a': 0.01, 'b': 0.015}

salary = float(input("whats your salary? "))
category = input("whats your category(A,B)? ")

final_salary = salary*(1+increase[category.lower()])
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `.get` to take into account for keys not present(for example category 'c')
`final_salary = salary*(1+increase.get(category.lower(), 0))`

Comment: that's a good idea. another solution could be to raise an error in case the category is not existing. that really depends on how OP will use the code

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
category_rates = {"A": 0.01, "B": 0.015}
final_salary = salary + (salary * category_rates[Category])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another variable called `increase`, and assign it a proper value depending on the category input.

```
Category = input("whats your category(A,B)? ")
if Category == "A":
    increase = 0.01
elif Category == "B":
    increase = 0.015
final_salary = salary + (salary* increase)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
salary = float(input("whats your salary? "))
Category = input("whats your category(A,B)? ")

if Category == "A":
    increase = 0.01
elif Category == "B":
    increase = 0.015
else:
    print("incorrect Category")

final_salary = salary + (salary * increase)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
category_dictionary = {'A':1,'B':1.5}
salary = float(input("whats your salary? "))
Category = input("whats your category(A,B)? ")
if Category in category_dictionary :
    new_salary = salary + salary * (category_dictionary[Category]/100) 
    print('New salary : ' + str(new_salary))
else :
    print('Wrong input')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).